# “Windows protected your PC”

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-smartscreen

> *Microsoft Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk.*

I often get the message above for executables downloaded from the internet.

- After I click »*Run anyway*« where exactly is this saved so I am not
  asked again?
- What is the reason that some unsigned apps cause this prompt and
  others don't?
- Does Windows know which files were downloaded form the internet and
  how to programmatically access or modify this meta data? It never asked me this for executables I compiled form source.

[image]

Comment: [How Windows knows it’s from the internet.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/6e3f7352-d11c-4d76-8c39-2516a9df36e8)

Comment: [How do I programmatically Unblock (IE feature) a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142826/how-do-i-programmatically-unblock-ie-feature-a-file)

Comment: @DanielB and @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 thanks for the links. I got it to work with PS commands `Set-Content` and `Get-Content` and then I also found https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams a neat tool that can query or delete `Zone-Identifier`. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49583470/block-a-file-with-powershell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It flags it due to an unknown publisher, not because it is malicious.

If you trust it then run anyway.

You can download it to a folder then scan it, see if it flags at as malicious.